# "top" like utility for AMD GPUs on a headless machine

Tags: debian, amd-radeon, debian-squeeze, top, headless

For monitoring CPU usage, there is `top` (well, I use [`htop`](http://htop.sourceforge.net/)).  Is there a `top`-like utility for GPUs?

I have an ATI Radeon HD 4650 in a computer running Debian Squeeze (x86).  Thing is, it's running headless, so I don't want a utility that requires X.

I've searched and only found nVidia stuff, and stuff that requires X.

I know `lm_sensors` can tell me the temperature, but I want to see the GPU usage.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the impetus for looking at GPU load on a headless machine? Are you delegating non-graphical processing to the GPU?

Comment: @asfallows: OpenCL apps.  Such as Bitcoin mining.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what I've found, there isn't already a tool like `top` or `conky` for GPU load, but for ATI cards, you can get a decent amount of information from `aticonfig`, and you can also add checks of that information to a conky config.

I found information that will probably be useful [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1566126). A help page for `aticonfig` can be found [here](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Aticonfighelp).

Comment: Thanks.  I figured `aticonfig` could do it, but its got way too many options.